# how to move polygon points depending on movement of one point?

Tags: actionscript-3

i have polygon say (Hexagonal with 6 lines) this Hexagonal connected from center with 6 point That make 6 triangles
I need when move any point(cause to move triangles) ,, other points move like this point i mean if the left point move to lift other points move to the left and so on

the code I want like this ptcP1.x and ptcP1.y the point that i moving it other point move depend on ptcP1 movement note that, this equations work fine in square shape ,, put in Penta and hexa ..etc this equations in valid so can any one help me

```
function button1_triggeredHandler( event:Event ):void
{

    mode="mode2";
    //trace(list.selectedIndex);

    if(list.selectedIndex==1)
    {
    DrawSqure.ptcP1.x = Math.random() + 50; 
    DrawSqure.ptcP1.y = Math.random() + 50;


    DrawSqure.ptcP2.y = 50-DrawSqure.ptcP1.x; 
    DrawSqure.ptcP2.x = DrawSqure.ptcP1.y;

    DrawSqure.ptcP3.x = 50-DrawSqure.ptcP1.y;
    DrawSqure.ptcP3.y = DrawSqure.ptcP1.x;


    DrawSqure.ptcP4.x = 50-DrawSqure.ptcP1.x; 
    DrawSqure.ptcP4.y = 50-DrawSqure.ptcP1.y;
}
```

Comment: Why not keep an array of all the points of that objects and when a point is being moved - apply the new position (translation) to all points?

Comment: Are you doing this on the timeline? Also @Creative Magic's solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, storing the vertices/points into a container (`Array` or `Vector`) and then adjusting those positions when you move is the best way to do it. Here is an example of how that might work:

```
//setup array or vector of vertices
var polygonVertices:Array = [DrawPolygon.ptcP1, DrawPolygon.ptcP2, DrawPolygon.ptcP3, DrawPolygon.ptcP4];
```

This method will take all the vertices and apply the translation:

```
//function for adjusting all the vertices based on the distance you pass
function moveShape( vertices:Array, dx:Number, dy:Number ) {
    var i:int;
    for ( ; i < vertices.length; i++ ) {
        vertices[i].x += dx;
        vertices[i].y += dy;
    }   
}
```

Then you would just need to know your distance X & Y your shape has moved and you can call `moveShape( polygonVertices, 100, 100 );`

I inserted 100,100 as the distance parameters as an example, but this should give you the results you are looking for.